# How to Update Another List Item Value Whenever Current Item is Approved

Tags: 2013, workflow, calendar, approval

I would like the following functionality:

- Approve a calendar item
- Run some workflow which will update a value on another list

I have tried the following `Item Change` workflow using both `2010` and `2013` WorkFlows, but without any success:

**Item Changed Workflow:**

[image]

**2010:** The workflow ends with an error, but no error details are supplied apart from `Status:   Error Occurred`

**2013:** The workflow appears to run, but after it is finished the approval status remains as `Pending` and the item in `AssetList` was never updated.